updatePassword error auth/requires-recent-login even after reauthenticate
I'm using "firebase": "^10.13.0" for user authentication in next.js 14.2 and typescript.
I'm unable to update the user password as I constantly get the auth/requires-recent-login error even after reauthentication.
I would think that after a reauthentication the user has at least a minute to update the Password before the last login is "too long ago" again.
I now directly call the updatePassword function after a successful reauthentication but even that does not work.
This is my workflow:
updateUserPassword:
function updateUserPassword(password: string): void {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const user = auth.currentUser;

  if (user) {
    updatePassword(user, password)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Password updated!");
      })
      .catch((error: Error) => {
        console.log("Error updateUserPassword: " + error.message);
        if (error.message.includes("auth/requires-recent-login")) {
          console.log("reauthUser");
          reauthUser(password);
        }
      });
  } else {
    console.log("User is not authenticated");
  }
}

reauthUser:
const reauthUser = async (password: string): Promise<void> => {
  const auth = getAuth();

  if (auth.currentUser) {
    const providerId = auth.currentUser.providerData[0]?.providerId;
    console.log("providerId: ", providerId);

    if (providerId === "google.com") {
      await reauthWithGoogle();
      updatePassword(auth.currentUser, password)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Password updated!");
        })
        .catch((error: Error) => {
          console.log(
            "Error updateUserPassword in reauthUser: " + error.message,
          );
        });
    } else {
      alert("Unsupported authentication provider.");
    }
  } else {
    router.push(ROUTES.signin);
  }
};

reauthWithGoogle
const reauthWithGoogle = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const auth = getAuth();
  googleProvider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: "select_account" });

  if (auth.currentUser) {
    reauthenticateWithPopup(auth.currentUser, googleProvider)
      .then(async (result) => {
        console.log("reauthenticateWithPopup");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert("Error reauthenticateWithPopup: " + error.message);
      });
  } else {
    router.push(ROUTES.signin);
  }
};


When it comes to Firebase Authentication, there are some operations that can be considered sensitive. For instance, changing (updating) a user’s password is indeed a security-sensitive operation that requires a recent login from the user. So each time when you need to perform such an operation, you should reauthenticate the users.
There are two solutions that can help you solve this problem, you either reauthenticate the user by asking for the credentials without signing out or you can sign the user out and let the user authenticate again.

Hey, smaica. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
